# Identificar tamanho de tela para carregar conteúdo de forma assíncrona

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um script que faz `reload` de 10 em 10 segundos, carregando uma página em uma `div`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var tempo = 10000;
    function listar() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"lista.php",
            success: function (textStatus) {      
                $('#lista').html(textStatus);
            }
        }); 
    }

    function reload() {
        location.reload();
    }

    $(function() {  
        listar();
        setInterval(listar, tempo);
        setInterval(reload, 1800000);
    });

</script>
```

---

Gostaria que o próprio **script**, **reconhecesse o tipo/tamanho de tela** (monitor, celular, etc) e carregasse o arquivo referente ao tamanho.

Exemplo:

Quando a tela for um **monitor**: carregar **lista.php**

Quando a tela for um **celular**: carregar **lista_cel.php**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você poderia capturar a tamanho da tela e com isso fazer a condição para verificar o tamanho de tela e dizer qual arquivo php será chamado.

Adicionando o codigo seguinte você irá pegar as dimensões da janela:

```
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

Alterando a função `listar()` para `listar(arquivo)`, para receber o arquivo que será chamado:

```
function listar(arquivo) {
    $.ajax({
        url: arquivo,
        success: function (textStatus) {      
            $('#lista').html(textStatus);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Por fim, usa a variável windowWidth para receber a largura da tela e faz as condições, verificando a largura e setando qual arquivo será chamado.

```
$(function() {
    var arquivo = "lista.php";

    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    if (windowWidth < 1000 && windowWidth >= 400)
        arquivo = "lista_tablet.php";
    else
    if (windowWidth < 400)
        arquivo = "lista_cel.php";

    listar(arquivo);
    setInterval(listar(arquivo), tempo);
    setInterval(reload, 1800000);
});
```

Comment: Thiago, consegui testar agora cara. Então, fiz como disse, mas o reload está travando a página. Pelo que vi, ele está recarregando a página inteira, várias e várias vezes. Parece que entra em loop cada vez maior. Antes de alterar, ele só carregava o "listar.php". Está funcionando, mas ele está com esse loop que cresce cada vez mais.

Comment: Joguei o IF para dentro da função `listar()` e deu certo!